# Redux: How to pass store to form created outside the Provider scope

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I have written code, which uses a Modal dialog to display a form.
My react app is rendered at "root"

**index.html**

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

**App.js**

```
const store = configureStore();

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
            <ExampleBasic/>
      </Provider>
      , document.getElementById('root'));
```

**ExmpleBasic.js**

Please ignore state management in component here. this is just for example.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import Lorem from 'react-lorem-component';
import Modal from '@atlaskit/modal-dialog';
import Button from '@atlaskit/button';

export default class ExampleBasic extends PureComponent {
  state = { isOpen: false }
  open = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true })
  close = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false })
  secondaryAction = ({ target }) => console.log(target.innerText)

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    const actions = [
      { text: 'Close', onClick: this.close },
      { text: 'Secondary Action', onClick: this.secondaryAction },
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.open}>Open Modal</Button>

        {isOpen && (
          <Modal
            actions={actions}
            onClose={this.close}
            heading="Modal Title"
          >
            <BasicFormContainer />
          </Modal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**BasicFormContainer.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  addDesignation: state.designations.addDesignation,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BasicForm);
```

**BasicForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class BasicForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  submit(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
        <Field
          name="designationName"
          component="input"
          placeholder="Name"
          label="Enter name"
          autoFocus
        />
      </form>

    );
  }
}


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'BasicForm',
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(BasicForm);
```

However modal is rendered using portal, outside current DOM.

As modal is rendered outside the scope of redux context, it is not getting the
store. and i am getting an error "Uncaught Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()"

Below is link to same kind of problem, where redux form within portal is not working. 
[Redux Form Wrapped Inside Custom Portal Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723396/redux-form-wrapped-inside-custom-portal-component)

Answer (score 2):

in React 16 it is handled by portals, but version before then that you can try something like as follow.

```
export default class ExampleBasic extends PureComponent {
  ...

  static contextTypes = { store: React.PropTypes.object };
  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    const actions = [
      { text: 'Close', onClick: this.close },
      { text: 'Secondary Action', onClick: this.secondaryAction },
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.open}>Open Modal</Button>

        {isOpen && (
          <Modal
            actions={actions}
            onClose={this.close}
            heading="Modal Title"
          >
            <Provider store={this.context.store}>
               <BasicFormContainer />
            </Provider>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the values of **BasicForm.js** to the Redux store and dispatch an action from there itself and not from the **BasicFormContainer.js**. This way, the **Modal** remains inside of the scope of your `root` element and thus there is no need to access the store outside of the  `Provider`.

Then update the Redux store based on the values entered in the form. Once, the store is updated, you can then access it from anywhere in your application such as **Modal** in your case.

Comment: This "Modal" component displays content in a layer that sits above the rest of the page content. It is a third party component. <body> <div id="root"/> <div>modal is rendered here </div> </body>

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to version 2.1.0 to solve the problem.

Comment: yes. I also used previous version of Modal, till this is resolved. But problem still exists